# where to configure applicationUserManager and role manager in aspnet Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, ef-code-first, asp.net-identity

First Of all, i have used **AspNet Identity Sample -pre installed through package manager console** but there was mismatch in razor file so intellisense stopped working on view pages.

So, i opted to manually put all the code files step by step and resolved missing using as they come in my way.
So, i have a identityConfig.cs file in my App_Start folder like this----

```
   public class IdentityConfig
   {
    public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
     {
        public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
            : base(store)
        {
        }
       public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options,
            IOwinContext context)
        {
            var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
            // Configure validation logic for usernames
            manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
            {
                AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
                RequireUniqueEmail = true
            };
```

and in my Account Controller, i have code like this-------

```
   public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public AccountController()
    {
    }

    public AccountController(IdentityConfig.ApplicationUserManager userManager, IdentityConfig.ApplicationSignInManager signInManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
        SignInManager = signInManager;
    }

    private IdentityConfig.ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
    public IdentityConfig.ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<IdentityConfig.ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }
```

Now, i am getting error in the Register Action method------

```
      public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser
            {
                UserName = model.Email,
                Email = model.Email
            };

            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

            //  await UserManager.SetTwoFactorEnabledAsync(user.Id, true);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return await GenerateEmailConfirmation(user);
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

here, as u can see, in the sixth line, it is giving System.NullReferenceException at line-------

```
   var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

i have tried to debug it, in my local window, it is passing every thing needed to populate the database correctly but only this result variable is null.also,
_signInManager, userManager and SignInManager and USerManager all are showing null in the locals window.

What is the problem.What i am missing. Please tell me. there is something to do with this UserMAnager class.I dont know what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have them created in your startup class:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thnxx for the help its working like a charm thnkk u very very much.Plzz explain me why it was needed to configure here. In aspnet Identity Sample, there was no requirement to configure it like this.

Comment: return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<IdentityConfig.ApplicationUserManager>(); ... You are getting your usermanager from your OwinContext, so at startup of the application, you have to be sure it will be in there...

Comment: I am having problem in following question can have a look this and suggest me what should i do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33455346/userid-not-found-error-in-aspnet-identity-at-generateuseridentityasync-method?noredirect=1#comment54697266_33455346