# UserId not found error in aspnet Identity at GenerateUserIdentityAsync method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

**I am getting UserId not found error after registring a user and also after login.Moreoever, after registration, data is saved to database and in dbo.AspNetUsers table, id column is auto incremented and return type is int.
There is UserId Column in AspNetUserClaims table.It has 4 Col---Id,UserId,ClaimType,ClaimValue.It has Id column as auto incremented not the userId.**
I was initially successfully changed Primary key from string to int by following this link---http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity.

It was running succesfully before but now it is giving me error at this line---

```
  public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser, int> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
```

**Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: UserId not found.**
This is the complete stack trace. you can see it here----http://pastebin.com/0hp5eAnp

It was working fine earlier but now when i added foreign key relationship with other tables, i don't know what is missing there. In the database all the tables are created properly with proper relationship between them but something is missing here.

**My ApplicationUser class is something like this-------**

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
 {
    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        this.Posts = new HashSet<Post>();
    }
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser, int> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
    public class CustomUserRole : IdentityUserRole<int> { }
    public class CustomUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<int> { }
    public class CustomUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<int> { }

    public class CustomRole : IdentityRole<int, CustomUserRole>
   {
    public CustomRole() { }
    public CustomRole(string name) { Name = name; }
}

public class CustomUserStore : UserStore<ApplicationUser, CustomRole, int,
    CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
{
    public CustomUserStore(ApplicationDbContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }
}

public class CustomRoleStore : RoleStore<CustomRole, int, CustomUserRole>
{
    public CustomRoleStore(ApplicationDbContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }
}
```

**and my IdentityConfig.cs class file is something like this-------**

```
     // Configure the application user manager used in this application. UserManager is defined in ASP.NET Identity and is used by the application.
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser, int>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser, int> store)
        : base(store)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context) 
    {
        var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new CustomUserStore(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
        // Configure validation logic for usernames
        manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser, int>(manager)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
            RequireUniqueEmail = true
        };

        // Configure validation logic for passwords
        manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 1,
            //RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
            //RequireDigit = true,
            //RequireLowercase = true,
            //RequireUppercase = true,
        };

        // Configure user lockout defaults
        manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
        manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;

        // Register two factor authentication providers. This application uses Phone and Emails as a step of receiving a code for verifying the user
        // You can write your own provider and plug it in here.
        manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Phone Code", new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<ApplicationUser, int>
        {
            MessageFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
        });
        manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Email Code", new EmailTokenProvider<ApplicationUser, int>
        {
            Subject = "Security Code",
            BodyFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
        });
        manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
        manager.SmsService = new SmsService();
        var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            manager.UserTokenProvider = 
                new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser, int>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
        }
        return manager;
    }
}

// Configure the application sign-in manager which is used in this application.
public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser, int>
{
    public ApplicationSignInManager(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
        : base(userManager, authenticationManager)
    {
    }

    public override Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        return user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync((ApplicationUserManager)UserManager);
    }

    public static ApplicationSignInManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationSignInManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        return new ApplicationSignInManager(context.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>(), context.Authentication);
    }
}
```

i have seen many stackoverflow answers but not getting it to work.Can someone plzz plzz see what is missing, what should i do now.thanks in advance.
Here, in the applicationUser class, at the Id column, it showing some warning and message in tooltip like this-------
     **models.ApplicationUSer.ID hides inherited member 
       Microsoft.Aspnet.Identity.EntityFramework.IDentity
       USer.Id. To make current member override
that implementation, add override keyword otherwise
add new keyword** where x is just the namespace.

My StartUp.Auth.cs in App_Start folder is like this------

```
     public partial class Startup
    {
     public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
     {
        // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        // Configure the sign in cookie
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser, int>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentityCallback: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager), getUserIdCallback:(id)=>(id.GetUserId<int>()))
            }
        });            
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        // Enables the application to temporarily store user information when they are verifying the second factor in the two-factor authentication process.
        app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

        // Enables the application to remember the second login verification factor such as phone or email.
        // Once you check this option, your second step of verification during the login process will be remembered on the device where you logged in from.
        // This is similar to the RememberMe option when you log in.
        app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);

        // Uncomment the following lines to enable logging in with third party login providers
        //app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(
        //    clientId: "",
        //    clientSecret: "");......................................................................
```

and my startUp.cs file is like this----

```
   [assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(WebApp.Startup))]
   namespace WebApp
   {
    public partial class Startup
   {
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
    }
   }
  }
```

Comment: Have you added auto increment to your UserId column in database?

Comment: @FSou1 it is auto increment by default i dont need to explicitly define it

Comment: @FSou1 I have updated the questions with extra details. If u can help me out, plzz suggest me what should i do now

Comment: Ohh my goodness i am also getting the same error. i have tried updating all the packages but nothing is working @duke

Comment: Could you put your startup code here also? I have an idea your configuring your startup with wrong userStore?

Comment: @JelleOosterbosch i have put the startUp code in the question

Answer (score 0):

You will have to pull out your ApplicationUserManager to have it nice and clean and implement more methods... For example see following post (It implemented all methods with your custom Key (TKey in the example):

http://www.symbolsource.org/MyGet/Metadata/aspnetwebstacknightly/Project/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/2.0.0-beta1-140211/Release/Default/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/UserManager.cs?ImageName=Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core

You will see that the error you receive **GetSecurityStampAsync** also is implemented there.

Comment: okk i will try to implement it as soon as possible thnxx for the help

Comment: Sir,the code is too much just for changing primary key return type from string to int. from seeing my code,can u list some of the methods needed for it to make it work. it will be great help for a newbie like me. hope u can understand my level

Comment: Is there any working sample available on net with primary key changed to int and additional methods therein added so i can get better understanding or any other way of removing some of the methods not needed in my solution to make it working

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/777733/ASP-NET-Identity-Change-Primary-Key ... This should be a working example, in my experience, don't change the primary key :)

Comment: thnxx for the help sir. i got it working. There was a silly mistake.

Comment: No problem, silly mistakes are often the cause of big problems, been there :).. Good luck...